# Rebase multiple commits into one

Tags: git, git-rebase

How can I quickly rebase this branch:

```
(MAJOR-A) <-- (minor-1) <-- (minor-2) <-- (MAJOR-B) <-- (minor-3) <-- master
```

To this one:

```
(MAJOR-A) <-- (MAJOR-B) <-- (merged-minors) <-- master
```

The `(merged-minors)` commit's place has no real matter, it could be as well:

```
(merged-minors) <-- (MAJOR-A) <-- (MAJOR-B) <-- master
```

Sorry for duplicate, but I'm lost about how to do it, even if I guess it deals with `git 
rebase -i` and the `squash` keyword.

The best answer would be a git command to execute, instead of a link to a whole english doc to translate... thanks in advance.

Comment: How about a link to a video tutorial :) - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IfkL8swmFw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git rebase -i HEAD~5

First just change lines of both Majors behind minors (change order of them).
After that change pick on two of minors to s to get one squashed commit.

so you have in rebase menu:

1. pick Major B
2. pick Major A
3. pick minor
4. s minor
5. s minor

But the best way to do this for newbies is to make local branch and test everything there. Rebase is powerful and easy tool if you understand how it works.

Comment: Tx, i was missing you could move the lines inside rebase menu